# Change the action of window.open

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.open

I want to know is it possible to change to action of `window.open`?
I mean I am using js file hosted of another domain and it have code in it for `window.open`, but I want to show that url instead of opening so is it possible to listen for window open event and then prevent default.

Answer (score 2):

You can override window.open() :

```
var nativeWinOpen = window.open;

window.open = function(){
    // do your mal ;) things here
    nativeWinOpen.apply(window,arguments);
}
```

If you want, you can remove the native function invocation...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
window.open = null;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78bjvedq/1/)

---

But try to catch the event instead.
Does the element have an ID / unique class ? Or its parents ?

Then add those lines

```
var element = document.getElementById('elementId');

element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help your code is working good but i still have some problem.
your code is working fine is js file is using simple window.open but the file i am using have like t.window.open and it is not working with it. below is the code which is in that js file.

`'\x75': function(t) {
            var e;
            try {
                e = t.window.open(z);
                e.focus();
                e.close();
            } catch (i) {}
            e = Dt(z);
            e.focus();
            e.close();
        }`